# Can I change the username in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

Does anybody know if the username in Google Earth Engine can be changed? I signed up for GEE a while ago and without knowing what I was doing, I assigned it a username which was more the name of a project rather than a user name for the GEE account. Now I am stuck with it and I can't find any information on how to change it. The only answer I found related to this issue is here:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/362523/google-earth-engine-rename-assets

where it is suggested that in order to change the username we have to contact Google. Is that true?

Thank you!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

After joining a GEE support group I learned that it is indeed not possible to change the username. This is something that needs to be requested directly to Google.

Comment: Note: At this time, the Earth Engine team can not support requests to change username.